# Apply 2 calcul in the same column - Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to apply a calculation in a column in 2 cases:

1. When the `Etablissements` in: `("E10", "E20")`
   Then apply this calcul: `Price * 10` in the column name: `Calcul`
2. When `Etablissement` in `("E30", "E40")` then apply another calcul in the same column `Calcul`: `Price * 50`

I wish that you get it, and thank you.

Comment: Look at the SQL Case expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want `CASE` expression :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN Etablissements in ('E10','E20')  
             THEN Price*10
             WHEN Etablissement in ('E30','E40') 
             THEN Price*50
        END) AS Calcul
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, i found a solution by your help :

Comment: SELECT *,

CASE
          WHEN gl_etablissement in ("w01","w05") THEN (price)*(10.95)
          WHEN gl_etablissement in ("c30","c40") THEN (price)/(2)
END AS "Price"

FROM Table